# How to set CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES for one CocoaPod?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm using an external CocoaPod.

To avoid build issues I need to set `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES` to `YES`.

I know how to do this by changing the `.podspec` file: adding a setting to `s.pod_target_xcconfig`.

Is there way to set `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES` to `YES` from my `Podfile` for example, or is there another way?